# Logging requests on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-diagnostics, azure-log-analytics

I have an Azure Service Bus, and started getting a huge amount of incoming requests (**sum** is huge and **count** not that much, seems to be similar messages).

The question is, is there a way I can really log those requests, taking the message sent to the queue and where it came from?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no built-in feature to log messages as is.

One way to achieve this would be to send messages to a topic instead and have 2 subscriptions - one which logs the incoming messages and the other would be the service that process the same messages.